# Back-Tick and Single Quote in ABAP

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting, abap, lexical-analysis

If I wanted to store the following string literal in a variable :

```
ab'c'd
```

Then what are the various ways to do it, using a single quote (') and/or a back-tick (`) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two choices:

Single Quotes:

```
   var = 'ab''c''d'.
```

Back Tick:

```
   var = `ab'c'd`.
```

Using the Back Tick is the simpler solution, assuming you're only concerned about single quotes.

Comment: Agreed.  It's worth mentioning string templates but that wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes should be usually "quoted" with backticks.